# Customize/format navbar when uncollapsed (navbar-collapse collapse in). MVC

Tags: html, css, asp.net-mvc

I am having trouble formatting the list items inside of the nav navbar-nav unordered list.  When the page is full size I want to leave the formatting as is.  However, I want to format/customize the list items when the page is shrunk and the list items "disappear" and only "reappear" once the user clicks the toggle button.

I have tried using **@media (max-width: 767px)** but it does not work.

Can somebody please help with this?

Comment: Please share your .cstml and corresponding CSS.

Answer (score 0):

I´ve done something similar recently but i used jquery, created a cookie and set it to 0 if its closed and 1 if its opened, something like this:

```
function toggleSideBar() {
$('#barsMenu').on("click", function () {
    $(this).toggleClass("closed");
    if ($(this).hasClass("closed")) {
        $.cookie('sideBarState', '0', { path: '/' });
    } else {
        $.cookie('sideBarState', '1', { path: '/' });
    }

if ($.cookie('sideBarState')==0) {
    $('#navigation').toggleClass("closed");
    $('#barsMenu').toggleClass("closed");
    $('.body-content').toggleClass("closed");
}
});
```

}